# Java packaging issue

Tags: java, classpath

I have an application that I've developed. Currently it is deployed with all its config files (including `log4j.properties`, as used by some external libs I use) in the same dir as my application.

So, I have a `bin` dir, containing my `app.jar`, plus a few properties files, plus a `lib` dir with all my external jars. The external jars are specified in a classpath specified in the `app.jar`'s manifest file.

Now the powers that be have decreed that the new structure will be a `bin` dir with just the `app.jar`, with a `lib` dir at the same level (i.e. `../lib`, relative to `bin`) for external jars and a `../etc` directory for configuration files.

Easy enough, I thought -- I changed all the classpath paths from `./lib/<jarname>` to `../lib/<jarname>`, and added `../etc` to the classpath as well.

Problem is that now any jars that use log4j don't work -- they don't see the `log4j.properties` file -- because, I suspect, the classpath for `app.jar` doesn't affect the classpath for the external jars (maybe?), and previously they were finding it simply because it was in '.'.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the log4j.properties anywhere as long as it is in the classpath. so, as @skaffman suggested, put the log4j properties file in the etc directory which is already in your classpath.

An alternative to using PropertyConfigurator is to set this syetm property while running your app.

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue is that Log4J now doesn't find the configuration file (log4j.properties) automatically anymore?

As far as I know, Log4J by default looks in the directories that are in the classpath for the log4j.properties file. Try adding the ../etc directory in the classpath in the manifest file of your JAR.

See also [Default Initialization Procedure](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit) in the Log4J Manual, it explains how Log4J looks for the configuration file and how you can change this.

Answer (score 0):

`log4j.properties` has to be somewhere in the default package, which in your case probably means in a JAR file somewhere in the root directory of that jar file.

A better solution would be to stick it in the `etc` directory, and then explicitly configure log4j to use it from that location. You can do that using [PropertyConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html) - invoke that when your application starts up, by filename, URL, whatever suits you best.